# How do I stop my iPhone from telling me by voice what keys I press and instead respond to them

Tags: iphone

[image]

How do I stop my iPhone 5s from voice identifying what keys impress and actually respond and accept the keys I press?

Comment: Do you have any of the `Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Speech` features turned on (assuming you have iOS 11)?

Answer (score -1):

Your device currently has on a feature called voice over which is made for people who are visually impaired.
One touch tells you what you have pressed, two touches will actually perform the intended action.

Triple clicking the home button typically turns off the voice over feature unless you have the magnifier enabled.

Once you have unlocked your device:

-go to settings, use the tap sequence 
-three finger scroll to get to general than use the tap sequence
-three finger scroll to accessibility ,use the tap sequence and turn off the voice over, once again using the tap sequence.

Comment: What does that do?  On my phone it opens magnifier, but I set that up.

Comment: It usually turns off voice over. You need to double tap on each number of your passcode to unlock the device, than you can ask Siri to turn off voice over.